# Inertia - append custom attribute only on demand - without $appends, with implicit model binding in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I need appending custom attribute only when I want this. I want to optimize sending data, not always I want this custom attribute.
In other words I need [this eloquent-serialization#appending-at-run-time](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-at-run-time) but in model directly.

In model I have:

```
protected function qrCode(): Attribute
{
    return new Attribute(
        get: fn () => $this->generateQrCode($this->code),
    );
}
```

In controller implicit model binding:

```
public function show(Code $code)
{
    $code->append('qr_code');
    $code->load('offer','user:name');
    return Inertia::render...
}
```

But It Doesn't work.

With: `$code->append('qr_code')->toArray()` It will but later I need relations and pass it to inertia, so I want to stick with Model type.

**Temporary solution:**
for now only option is to make custom function in Model but maybe there is other?

```
public function appendCustom($column) {
    return $this[$column] = $this->{$column};
}
```

Comment: What you can do is append attributes directly on the model and then use `makeHidden` to exclude them when necessary. But I don't know if that's better or worse since it will require you to hide those attributes in multiple places...